# HttpClient exception when server closes connection after writing response headers

Tags: c#, http, dotnet-httpclient

I am using `HttpClient` to PUT data to a HTTP server using `PutAsync`.

When the server sends back an error code (e.g. 401 Unauthorized), it closes the connection (having provided the Connection: close header in its response). When that happens, HttpClient throws System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException (Error while copying content to a stream) with the inner exceptions listed below. This seems to be linked to writing the data out (despite the fact it's in BeginRead) since if I persuade the server to read all the data being sent then the exception is not thrown.

I can work around the problem by using `HttpClient.SendAsync` to do the same task with the `HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead` argument. In this case the exception is not thrown and I can read the `HttpResponseMessage.StatusCode`.

My question is, is the exception correct? i.e. is the server not following a standard by closing the connection without reading all the data that it does not need? If not then is there a problem with `PutAsync` in that it does not allow access to the return `StatusCode` in this situation?

Sample code:

```
using (FileStream stream = File.OpenRead(FilePath))
using (StreamContent content = new StreamContent(stream))
using (HttpRequestMessage req = new HttpRequestMessage
    {
        Method = HttpMethod.Put,
        RequestUri = new Uri(baseUri, Path),
        Content = content,
    })
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{
    req.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(FileContentType);
    // This version works:
    //using (HttpResponseMessage resp = await client.SendAsync(req,
    //    HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead))
    // This version throws an exception:
    using (HttpResponseMessage resp = await client.PutAsync(
        new Uri(baseUri, Path), content))
    {
        if (resp.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
        {
            // Try again with authorisation credentials based on resp.Headers.WwwAuthenticate
        }
    }
}
```

Inner exception: System.IO.IOException (Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.)

```
at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.BeginRead(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
at System.Net.PooledStream.BeginRead(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
at System.Net.ConnectStream.BeginReadWithoutValidation(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
at System.Net.ConnectStream.BeginRead(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.WebExceptionWrapperStream.BeginRead(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
at System.Net.Http.StreamToStreamCopy.StartRead()
```

with inner exception: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host)

```
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.BeginReceive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.BeginRead(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use HTTP Protocol Version 1.0 if it suits your needs:

```
using (HttpRequestMessage req = new HttpRequestMessage
    {
        Method = HttpMethod.Put,
        RequestUri = new Uri(baseUri, Path),
        Content = content,
        Version = HttpVersion.Version10
    })
```